# how to list records that conform to a sequentially incrementing id in postgres

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to select records are sequentially incremented?

for example, for a list of records

```
id 0
id 1
id 3
id 4
id 5
id 8
```

a command like:

```
select id incrementally from 3
```

Will return values `3`,`4` and `5`. It won't return `8` because it's not sequentially incrementing from `5`.

Comment: `select id from the_table where id >= 3 order by id` would be the obvious answer. From your example I'm guessing you want to skip gaps? If so you need to amend your question as sequential does not necessarily mean gapless.

Comment: The records are generated externally. The ids are being generated sequentially but can be placed into the database in any order. However, post processing requires that the records be sequentially processed and so it will stop if the next id is not found in the db. I'd like to be able to do the post processing in the database itself.

Comment: According to this [Sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence) going from 5 --> 8 is a sequence. You are going to need to define further what your idea of a sequence is and how you want to handle the gaps.

Comment: Please add the expected output...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d48df983dad317200ab95a6483d09a6b)

```
WITH groups AS (                                           -- 2
    SELECT
        *,
        id - row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id) as group_id   -- 1
    FROM mytable
)
SELECT                                                    
    *
FROM groups
WHERE group_id = (                                         -- 4
    SELECT group_id FROM groups WHERE id = 3               -- 3
)
```

1. `row_number()` window function create a consecutive row count. With this difference you are able to create groups of consecutive records (`id` values which are increasing by `1`)
2. This query is put into a `WITH` clause because we reuse the result twice in the next step
3. Select the recently created `group_id`
4. Filter the table for this group.

Additionally: If you want to start your output at `id = 4`, for example, you need to add a `AND id >= 4` filter to the `WHERE` clause

Comment: This hides the gaps, but does not address: '... post processing requires that the records be sequentially processed and so it will stop if the next id is not found in the db. ...' from @zcaudate comment to the question.

Comment: This works. it's magic. for processing, the `last-processed-id` is saved somewhere, a group is selected according to the last processed id and once it's done, the `last-processed-id` gets updated.